# Export two different list into one string

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

I have two different lists I want to export in single CSV file in ASP.NET

```
string listToString1= string.Join(",", list1.ToArray());
string listToString2= string.Join(",", list2.ToArray());
string finalstring = "Collection ID" + listToString1+ "," + "Collection Title" + listToString2;

return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(finalstring), "text/csv", "abcd.csv");
```

Here i am getting output like:

> Collection ID , id1,id2,id3
>
> Collection Title, Title1,Title2,Title3

But I want output to be like :

> Collection Id, Collection Title id1          , Title1 id2          ,
>   Title2 id3          , Title3

Here collection ids are in same column and collection titles are in same column

Comment: Add the two lists together : list1.AddRange(list2);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```
List<string> list1 = new List<string>() { "Collection ID", "id1", "id2" , "id3" };
List<string> list2 = new List<string>() { "Collection Title", "Title1", "Title2", "Title3" };
var result = string.Join(" ",list1.Zip(list2, (f,l) => f + "," + l));
```

You need to make sure that you've added the `System.Linq` to your `using` directive though