# Match two sequences

Tags: c#, linq

This may be a trivial question but could you please assist me with that.
There are two sequences with the same length.
`var a = new[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50}`
`var b = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
How to get in result such sequence:
`var result = {10 - 1, 20 - 2, 30 - 3, 40 - 4, 50 - 5}`
It is desirable to you selectMany or whatever.
Thank you!

Comment: Here is an example https://stackoverflow.com/a/60224284/2946329

Comment: `var r = a.Zip(b, (x, y) => x - y).ToArray();` (this is duplicate question tho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing Zip:

```
var a = new[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
var b = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

var result = a.Zip(b, (x,y)=> new {X=x, Y=y});
```

Comment: That does not produce `10 - 1`, but `{ X = 10, Y = 1 }`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere, You mean literally wanted the difference of 10 and 1? Then simply make that => x-y.

Comment: Thank you for responses!

Comment: @CetinBasoz The point in OPs question simply is, that´s it´s unclear if he/she wants really `"10 - 1"`, or if he wants to evaluate that expression (to `9`).

Comment: @HimBromBeere, just take the answer as the basis and then you can format the result to your hearts content.